# showing large amounts of output in Tkinter using yfinance

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, tkinter, yfinance

I am currently making a stock screener using Tkinter GUI and yfinance. My program generates the necessary data. But when the data is in large amount my program hides the rows and states something like: [365 rows x 6 columns], [5000 rows x 6 columns].

I think this is because there are too many rows to show all the necessary data for stocks. But is there a way to make Tkinter show me all of the rows of data?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You could insert the rows into a `Treeview` and use scrollbars to scroll

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will try to implement that to see whether that works.